# change letter to lowercast with haskell issue

Tags: haskell

i have this question:
"Write a Haskell function
isPalindrome :: [Char] -> Bool
to recognize palindromes like "Madam, I\'m Adam"
Notice you need to make all capital letters lower case and throw out punctuation before comparing."

i write this code in haskell:

```
import Char

lower :: String -> String
lower xs = [tolow ch| ch<-xs]

tolow :: Char -> Char
tolow ch 
    | isUpper  ch    = chr (ord ch + 32)
    | otherwise    = ch

isPalindrome :: [Char] -> Bool  
isPalindrome xs = xs == (reverse (lower xs))
```

excute:

Main> isPalindrome "DSD"

False

Main> isPalindrome "dsd"

True

it don't why it keep give me false with capital letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of `isPalindrome xs = xs == (reverse (lower xs))`

You lower-case only the reversed part of the comparison, while you should lower-case both.

Comment: Never mind. Also, consider using `map toLower` instead of your `tolow`; it will, among other things, handle Unicode correctly.

Comment: @user3061949 Also, to make sure that you aren't duplicating work, do something like `isPalindrome xs = let ys = map Data.Char.toLower xs in ys == reverse ys`, or an equivalent `where` clause.  This will keep you from converting each character to lower case twice.